# Magento server error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'fancybox_status'

Tags: ajax, magento, fancybox

Got this error in magento system.log when I try to print an order invoice:

> 2013-08-12T15:44:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal string offset
>   'fancybox_status'  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/meigeetheme/default/template/ajax/catalog/product/view/list.phtml
>   on line 193

On that line is this piece of code:

```
if ($fancybox['fancybox_status'] && $fancybox['fancybox_listing'] == 1): ?>
```

I really hope that one of you guys can help me out here, I don't have a clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

just in case anyone has the same problem just edit:
app/code/local/Meigee/ThemeOptions/Helper/Data.php

and change:

```
return Mage::getStoreConfig(‘meigee_general/fancybox/fancybox_status’);
```

to:

```
return Mage::getStoreConfig(‘meigee_general/fancybox’);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears [the theme you bought](http://meigeeteam.com/product/redress-magento-theme/livepreview/), or the customizations you've made to it, have a PHP error.  I don't have a copy of this theme, but it looks like theme expects the variable `$fancybox` in

```
app/design/frontend/meigeetheme/default/template/ajax/catalog/product/view/list.phtml
```

to be an array, but for some reason on your system, on that page, it's a string.  I'd contact the authors of the theme for support.  Credible Magento vendors will support problems with their themes (assuming you, or you contractors, haven't modified it yourself)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I will contact them. It's a theme via Themeforest so they must offer some kind of support, i guess ;)